# Reduce SQL Queries from Includes assoc

Tags: ruby, activerecord, include

I try to reduce SQL queries from my Rails application.
I have some controller like:

```
class Rest::MyController < Rest::BaseController
  def show
    render xml: some_model, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def my_associations
    [
      :model2,
      :model3,
      :model4,
    ]
  end

  def some_model
    @some_model ||= SomeModel.includes(my_associations).where(id: test_params[:id])
  end

  def test_params
    params.permit(:id)
  end
end
```

To avoid `N + 1` I use `includes`, so basically when i try to execute `some_model` method, AR make lot of call's like that (SELECT ALL FROM):

```
SomeModel Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `model2`.* FROM `model2` WHERE `model2`.`type` IN ('SomeModel') AND `model2`.`is_something` = 0 AND `model2`.`id` = 1
SomeModel Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `model3`.* FROM `model3` WHERE `model3`.`type` IN ('SomeModel') AND `model3`.`is_something` = 0 AND `model3`.`id` = 1
SomeModel Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `model4`.* FROM `model4` WHERE `model4`.`type` IN ('SomeModel') AND `model4`.`is_something` = 0 AND `model4`.`id` = 1
```

This is only example
Now, through my serializer I would like to get only selected columns for `model2`, `model3` and `model4`

Unfortunately Active record make a call like `SELECT model2.* FROM`

For example, for `model2` serializer i try to get only `(:id, :name)` columns.
Is it possible to make a call like ?

```
SELECT some_model.*, model2.id, model2.name FROM `some_model`
```

instead

```
SELECT `model2`.* FROM `model2` WHERE `model2`.`type` IN ('SomeModel')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rails's `includes` feature, then no, there isn't an especially good way to selectively control the columns from included models.

If you're looking for help to optimize the query, you'll need to provide more specifics about the data schema and the desired output.